# How to find patterns across multiple lines using perl

Tags: perl, sed

I want to grep some string spread along multiple lines withing some begin and end pattern

Example:

```
MediaHelper->fetchStrings( names => [  //Here new line may or many not be
**'ubp-firstrun_heading',
'firstrun_text',
'_firstrun-or-start_search',
'installed'**  //may end here also );
]);
```

using perl or grap how I can get list 4 strings here begin pattern is `MediaHelper->fetchStrings(names => [` and end pattern is `);`

Or any other suggesting using other commands like grep or sed or awk ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/MediaHelper->fetchStrings( names =>/,/);/ p' <yourfile>
```

Or, if you want to skip the delimiting lines, this:

```
sed -n '/MediaHelper->fetchStrings( names =>/,/);/ {/MediaHelper->fetchStrings( names =>/b; /^);/b; p}' <yourfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need to match all strings in all lines (and not just the MediaHelper thing).

If this is the case, then sed is the right tool, because it is by default line-oriented.

In our case, if you want to match the string in every line:

```
sed   "s/.*\('.*'\).*/\1/" <your_file>
```

Hope it helps

Edit: To be more descriptive, first we need to match the whole line (that's the first and the last .*)  and then we enclose in parenthesis the part of the line we want to print, which in our case is everything inside single quotes. The number 1 before the last delimiter denotes that we want to print the first (in our case it is the last also) parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Just process the file in slurp mode instead of line by line:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 while m{MediaHelper->fetchStrings(names\s*=>\s*\[(.*?)\]}g' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp mode instead of line by line
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.